# How to display validation messages without affecting centered content?

Tags: html, css

My form below (I've removed all the other rows) displays nicely centered within it's parent div. Problem is when I start editing fields, if there is a validation error, when the validation message appears to the right of the editor, the whole form re-centers for the new content width.  Very annoying. Then I tried moving all the ValidationFors into a separate right aligned div.  Same problem though. As soon as an error appeared in that right aligned div, the center form shifted over.

How can I:

1) Get the form to display centered, but then stop self centering after initial load?  It would be nice to have the validation messages appear just to the right of the editors, but I don't want the screen layout constantly changing.

2) Is there a way to preallocate some hidden width left and right so that the primary form elements (label & editor) stay centered and that the validation messages don't factor into the centering content?

```
 <table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
        <tr>
            <td class="FieldLabel">
                Name:
            </td>
            <td class="FieldEditor">
                @Form.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data.LocationName, new { style = "width:300px" })
                @Form.ValidationFor(model => model.Data.LocationName)
            </td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/murid/9m5gcare/1/

Add another "td" that will hold the error, keep it empty and fill it with the error when it's time to. Give it a width and give the form the same spacing to the left to align.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="FieldLabel">Name:</td>
        <td class="FieldEditor"><input type="text"></td>
        <td class="error"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

td:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 100px;
}

td.error {
    width: 100px;
    color: red;
}
```